# How count in Datalog?

Tags: prolog, datalog

I have this DB:

```
LABORATORY(LabNumber, SeatsNumber)
RESERVATION(LabNumber, ProfName, Date)
PROF(ProfName, Subject ,#Reservation)
```

How can I do this query in `PROLOG(DATALOG)`?

Find PROFessor's name who made more reservations

Comment: what system do you use ? It's DES ok ?

Comment: I am using SWI Prolog

Comment: Prolog is not Datalog. Retag your question accordingly